# Is there any Visual Studio 2010 add-in for formating C++ code?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, plugins, add-in

For example, I have following C programming language codes using **Visual studio 2010** for learning *Data structure* in **C++**:

> 

```
#include "stdio.h"
typedef int datatype;
#define m 100
#define n  10
typedef struct {int rear,front; datatype q[m];}SqQueue;
void enQueue(SqQueue &queue, datatype x)
{
  if ((queue.rear+1)%m==queue.front) printf("The queue is overflow"); 
else { queue.rear=(queue.rear+1)%m;queue.q[queue.rear]=x; }
}
void deQueue(SqQueue &queue, datatype *y)
{
  if (queue.front==queue.rear) printf("The queue is empty");
else {queue.front=(queue.front+1)%m;*y=queue.q[queue.front]; }
}
int main( )
{
 SqQueue queue; queue.front=queue.rear=0; int i,x,y;
 for(i=1; i<=n; i++) {scanf("%d",&x);  enQueue(queue,i);}
 for(i=1; i<=n; i++) {deQueue(queue,&y);printf("%d\t",y);}
 return 0;
}
```

**I want to get it formatted like this:**

> 

```
#include "stdio.h"
typedef int datatype;

#define m 100
#define n  10

typedef struct 
{
    int rear, front; 
    datatype q[m];
}SqQueue;


void enQueue(SqQueue &queue, datatype x)
{
    if ( (queue.rear + 1) % m == queue.front) 
        printf("The queue is overflow"); 
    else 
    { 
        queue.rear = ( queue.rear+1 ) % m;
        queue.q[queue.rear] = x; 
    }
}


void deQueue(SqQueue &queue, datatype *y)
{
    if (queue.front == queue.rear) 
        printf("The queue is empty");
    else 
    {
        queue.front= ( queue.front + 1 ) % m;
        *y = queue.q[queue.front]; 
    }
}

int main( )
{
    SqQueue queue; 
    queue.front = queue.rear = 0; 
    int i,x,y;

    for(i=1; i<=n; i++) 
    {
        scanf("%d",&x);  enQueue(queue,i);
    }

    for(i=1; i<=n; i++) 
    {
        deQueue(queue, &y); printf("%d\t",y);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I tried lots of add-ins in codeproject.com but without success to achieve such an effect. Thanks for your help!

Comment: By memory : Ctrl+A, Ctrl+K, Ctrl+F ?

Comment: VS 2015 will get you closer.

Comment: IIRC [VisualAssist](http://www.wholetomato.com/features/default.asp) improved the formatting in the older Visual Studios (besides a pile of other handy features).

Comment: 1. Don't use ancient compilers unless you HAVE to (unlikely if you're learning). Get yourself a VS2015 community. 2. Best formatting tool - [clang-format plugin for Visual Studio](http://llvm.org/builds/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend AStyle Extension. Before I transferred my code to VS 2015, it is the only tool I had found to format my code.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, astyle is also the addin that I had tried without success to get the effect as what I have shown in the post. Would you like to share some tips as for my need, thank you again!

Comment: I can't open its online help. Check this: http://astyle.sourceforge.net/astyle.html